# Span HTML Element behave like canvas line (x1,y1,x2,t2)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's a problem for someone relatively good at math. I have two boxes I want to connect to each other with a line made by a HTML element. Here is the code:

```js
var line = document.getElementById("line");

function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  // ...
}
```

```css
.box1, .box2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: #f00;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

.box1 {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.box2 {
  top: 200px;
  left: 150px;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <span class="line" id="line"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE** I want it to be responsive, so I can move the cubes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the math. The length of the line is: `√x²+y²` or in js: `Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y)`. And the rotation for the line is: `Math.ata2(height, width)` (the return value type is radians).

**Note!** Width and height is the width and height of a rectangle at both positions. So create a rectangle with the left and top at the first position and width and height so it reaches the second position.

**Note!** Remember to set `transform-origin: top left;` otherwise the element will rotate from the middle.

```
function getLineLength(width, height) {
  return Math.sqrt(width * width + height * height);
}

function getLineRotation(width, height) {
  return ((width * 2 - width * 1) / (width * 2 - width * 1)) * (180/Math.PI);
}
```